# Why does the "de" command delete the next word if the cursor is on the end of a word?

Tags: vim

When I put my cursor on the last character of a word and I input the `de` command, it deleted from last character of the current word to the end of the next word. Shouldn't it just delete to the last character of the current word?

Answer (score 0):

`w`, `W`, `e`, `E`, `b`, `B`, `ge`, and `gE` all…

- jump to the designated end of the current word/WORD *if they are not already there*,
- jump to the designated end of the next or previous word/WORD *if they are already on the designated end of the current word*.

`:help e` and friends could be more precise but the "Word movement" section in chapter 3 of the user manual (`:help 03.1`) is pretty clear.